# Uncaught ReferenceError: prueba is not defined at HTMLElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html5

Al llamar a una funcion en un script de javascript en tipo modulo, no me funciona, dice que no esta definido, pero en uno normal si me funciona.

Aqui si funciona.

```js
const prueba = id => console.log(id)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="prueba(15)">Prueba</button>
    <script src="./prueba.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Aqui no funciona.
Necesito que me funcione este.

```css
const prueba = id => console.log(id)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="prueba(15)">Prueba</button>
    <script type="module" src="./prueba.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es por un asunto de ámbito (`scope`), los modulos son accesible dentro de su propio ámbito no de forma global. Es decir solo puedes usar los elementos exportados dentro de la etiqueta `script type="module"`. La solución es asignar el evento de esa etiqueta en lugar de asignalo en el HTML

```
<button id="pruebabtn">Prueba</button>
<script type="module">
    import { prueba } from './prueba.js';
    pruebabtn.addEventListener("click",e=>prueba(15))
</script>
```

Además te falta agregar la palabra clave `export` en tu archivo './prueba.js'

```
export const prueba = id => console.log(id);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo del export se me paso